# Rails Kaminari - How to order/paginate arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm following the railscast for Kaminari (http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari). But I'm stuck with the controller part.

In my controller, I have something like this:

```
def index
  @articles = (params[:mine] == "true") ? current_user.articles : Article.search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @articles }
  end
end
```

And now I'm not sure how to chain the methods, order, page and per, like in the screencast `.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(5)`. I keep on getting the no method 'order' in Array. I know I can't call the methods on arrays but how else can I chain them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Kaminari on Arrays:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(@articles).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari):

> Kaminari provides an Array wrapper class that adapts a generic Array object to the `paginate` view helper. However, the `paginate` helper doesn’t automatically handle your Array object (this is intentional and by design). `Kaminari::paginate_array` method converts your Array object into a paginatable Array that accepts `page` method.